# TChromium в Delphi XE отображает страницу как HTML код

Tags: delphi-xe, компоненты

Я скачал **dcef3** из [репозитория](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) и хотел установить его в Delphi XE, но не смог найти `DCEF_XE.dpk`, поэтому я установил через `DCEF_D7.dpk`. Скомпилировал демо и запустил. В итоге получил вместо нормально страницы ее HTML код (это можно увидеть на скриншоте).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была в нехватке файлов "cef*" рядом с ЕХЕшником, после добавления все красиво заработало.

Добавил следующие файлы:

> cef.pak, cef_100_percent.pak, cef_200_percent.pak, cef_extensions.pak,
>   libcef.dll, libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll, cefclient.drc,
>   natives_blob.bin, snapshot_blob.bin, widevinecdmadapter.dll,
>   wow_helper.exe.

Возможно какие-то файлы лишние, но я их оставил.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/271810)

Comment: Автор вопроса я и я даю ответ, который будет понятен дельфийцам. Если ответ не понятен Вам, это не значит, что он не будет понятен другим, поэтому помечать ответ бесполезным, как минимум, некорректно.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что:

- Вы пытаетесь использовать компонент, который не предназначен для Вашей версии Delphi.
- Версия Delphi для которой он предназначен имеет массу отличий от той, что используете Вы.

Иначе говоря, Вы пытаетесь на Ferrari установить запчасти от "Жигулей".

Попробуйте использовать `dpk` для версии "по свежее" чем Delphi 7.

Comment: Пробовал. В версиях от XE2 и выше используется еще модуль `fmx` (как я понял, это `Firemonkey`), чего в ХЕ нет. Если этот модуль удалить из пакета и установить, то проблема с отображением не решиться.

Comment: @VJS, в таком случае только одно из трёх. Первое - дорабатывать компонент под имеющуюся версию Delphi. Второе - обновить версию Delphi (конечно, если позволяют возможности). Третье - попытаться отыскать готовую реализацию в сети (вдруг кто-то сделал и куда-нибудь выложил).

Comment: 1. Это где-то в DLL, так что этот вариант не очень подходит. 2. Писал бы для себя, обновил бы, а на работе надо еще уговорить купить обновление из-за компонента )) 3. Задал, но там очень подолгу отвечают (если отвечают). Надеялся, что кто-то сталкивался с таким и смог решить как-то еще проблему.

Comment: @VJS, понимаю. В таком случае остаётся только искать альтернативу TChromium. Как один из вариантов, стандартный TWebBrowser.

Comment: Поставил XE2, скомпилировал Демо в нем. Ошибка та же. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Понял, что это за текст. Фишка оказалась в том, что он отображает тэг JavaScript (не скрывает его почему-то). Может кто подскажет как сделать, чтоб скрывал?

Comment: На XE5 демо отображает все правильно, но когда создал свой проект и просто кинул компонент на форму, то ошибка та же.